# R8: NullPointerException during IR Conversion

Tags: java, android, firebase, proguard, android-r8

I have a problem when trying to generate a release version of my app. It gives a strange error

```
C:\Users\rshal\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6c326691eb00442622017dd95f96e92a\jetified-firebase-config-19.1.3-runtime.jar: R8: NullPointerException during IR Conversion
> Task :app:minifyProdReleaseWithR8 FAILED
```

I have been using firebase analytics and firebase remote config without problems. And also I had no issue this R8 minimization.
Recently I have integrated `google-speech-api` and after that, I am not able to use R8.

I did not have this problem until I integrated `google-speech-api` in the app. I know that  `google-speech-api` is not officially supported on Android. Maybe that is the core issue. Before that, I had an issue with `firebase-config` dependency. It is not compatible with the `google-speech-api` library I think. I solved that issue with this Gradle configuration

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-config', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf' // google-cloud-speech causes this. see  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1143
})
```

I have followed [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1143) fix.

Now I am stuck with this error that I showed above.

I have tried different versions on R8 as suggested [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150325706)

This is gradle build log

```
> Task :app:minifyProdReleaseWithR8
R8: Missing class: org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.ExtendedLoggerWrapper
R8: Missing class: org.eclipse.jetty.npn.NextProtoNego$ClientProvider
R8: Missing class: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
R8: Missing class: org.jboss.marshalling.ByteOutput
R8: Missing class: java.lang.ClassValue
R8: Missing class: org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN$ClientProvider
R8: Missing class: org.jboss.marshalling.ByteInput
R8: Missing class: org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN$ServerProvider
R8: Missing class: org.eclipse.jetty.npn.NextProtoNego$ServerProvider
R8: Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
R8: Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection implements program class org.apache.http.HttpConnection
C:\Users\rshal\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6c326691eb00442622017dd95f96e92a\jetified-firebase-config-19.1.3-runtime.jar: R8: NullPointerException during IR Conversion

> Task :app:minifyProdReleaseWithR8 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyProdReleaseWithR8'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complet
```

this is `build.gradle` [file](https://codeshare.io/50OyWl)

[this](https://codeshare.io/5gzoYR) is top-level Gradle file

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't. I think it's r8 related bug. I'm planning to submit a bug report. I have minimal Gradle configuration ready to reproduce this bug. I can share if you want

Comment: Yes I want it very much )

Comment: What version of grade plugin are you using? That's really important

Comment: i use 3.6.2 version

Comment: https://github.com/Rshalika/r8_bug_sample here is a repository. Just copy and run `gradlew assempleRelease`. It is not standard application code. Android studio will not import it correctly so just use a command line `gradlew`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211883/discussion-between-rezo-shalikashvili-and-maxp).

Comment: I simplify project. This is a standard project created in android studio with the addition of two dependencies using different versions of protobuf.

https://github.com/m4xp1/R8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question because it turned out to be an `R8` bug and after me reporting it, they solved the issue. Which is great.

Full bug report and how to apply **fix** is  [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154315490)

Short version:

change `gradle` configuration to this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
    }
}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.6.88'          // Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
     }
}
```

I have encountered this bug when implementing Google Speech API in my android app.
For anyone who might need it, this is my final `groguard` configuration

```
-keep class com.google.api.gax.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.cloud.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.api.services.translate.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.api.client.util.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.api.client.googleapis.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.cloud.speech.v1.stub.** {*;}
-keep class io.grpc.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.auth.oauth2.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.auth.** {*;}
```